# Pecorrer dicionário de dados python

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso percorrer um dicionário de dados Python, pegando os valores e contando as posições do inicio ao fim de cada valor de forma sequencial, transformando depois em uma tupla exemplo:

```
dict = {'dado1': 'teste01', 'dado2': 'teste002', 'dado3': 'teste0004050'}
```

`dado1` -> value: `teste01` - tem 7 caracteres que vai de 0 a 7

`dado2` -> value: `teste002` - tem 8 caracteres que vai de 8 a 15

`dado3` -> value: `teste0004050` - tem 12 caracteres que vai de 16 a 27

```
tupla = [(0,7),(8,15),(16,27)]
```

Comment: Poderia dizer qual o critério? Se tem 7 caracteres e sua indexação no array inicia em 0, então deveria ir até o 6, não?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro vamos percorrer o dicionário com um `for`. Ao mesmo tempo que fazemos a iteração no laço já montamos a saída do array `tupla`, que adicionamos o tamanho  da `string`, somado com o valor anterior, esses valores são armazenados temporariamente na variável `tmp`.

```
dict = {'dado1': 'teste01', 'dado2': 'teste002', 'dado3': 'teste0004050'}
tupla = []
inicio = 0
fim = 0
tmp = 0
for elem in dict:
    print(dict[elem])
    inicio = tmp
    fim = inicio + len(dict[elem])-1
    tmp = fim + 1
    tupla.append((inicio,fim))
print(tupla)
```

Answer (score 1):

Em python pode-se percorrer por um iterável usando algumas ferramentas:

- Iteração
- List comprehension
- Map
- Recursividade

#### A iteração é a repetição de um processo visando gerar um resultado.

> Na computação, iteração é a técnica de marcação de um bloco de
> instruções em um programa de computador por um número definido de
> repetições. Esse bloco de instruções é considerado iterativo ; um
> cientista da computação também pode se referir a esse bloco de
> instruções como uma "iteração".
>
> O pseudocódigo abaixo é um exemplo de iteração:
>
> ```
> for item in coleção:
>  faça algo com o item
> ```
>
> <sub>fonte: [wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration)</sub>

A declaração [`for`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) do Python itera sobre os itens de uma sequência ao em vez de especificar valores ou condições numéricas. É mais parecido a declaração [`foreach`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/La%C3%A7o_foreach) encontrada em outras lingagen

Aplicando iteração ao dicionário proposto na pergunta:

```python
f=0
l=[]

for s in dict.values():
  l.append((f, (f:= f + len(s)) - 1))

print(l)                               #[(0, 6), (7, 14), (15, 26)]
```

#### List comprehension é uma construção sintática disponível em algumas linguagens de programação para criar uma lista com base em listas existentes

> List comprehension ou abstrações de lista são estruturas sintáticas
> que descrevem como listas existentes ou outros objetos iteráveis ​​são
> processados ​​para criar novas listas a partir deles.
>
> Eles são escritos em algumas linguagens de programação como B, Python
> , Haskell ou Common Lisp com suporte e em analogia com a notação
> descritiva de conjuntos.
> <sub>fonte: [wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension)</sub>

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#expression-lists) oferece uma sintaxe mais compacta quando você deseja criar uma nova lista com base nos valores de uma lista existente.

Aplicando list comprehension ao dicionário proposto na pergunta:

```python
f=0
print([(f, (f:= f + len(s)) - 1) for s in dict.values()])   #[(0, 6), (7, 14), (15, 26)]
```

#### Map é uma função que aplica uma determinada função a uma iterável.

> Em muitas linguagens de programação, map uma função de ordem
> superior na qual uma determinada função é aplicada a cada elemento de
> um functor , por exemplo, em uma lista , o resultado é uma lista
> igualmente longa de resultados.
>
> Abaixo está um exemplo para adicionar 1 a cada número em uma lista:
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
> <sub>[fonte:wikpedia](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(hogere-ordefunctie))</sub>

A função [map()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) devolve um iterador que aplica uma fnçãopara cada item de um iterável.

Aplicando map ao dicionário proposto na pergunta:

```
def ccontador():
  f = 0                                  
  def contador(s):
    nonlocal f                            
    return (f, (f:= f + len(s)) - 1)
  return contador

cont = ccontador()

print([*map(cont, dict.values())])       #[(0, 6), (7, 14), (15, 26)]
```

#### Recursividade significa que, ao descrever algo, uma referência à própria descrição aparece na descrição.

> Em ciência da computação, a recursividade é a definição de uma
> sub-rotina (função ou método) que pode invocar a si mesma. Um exemplo
> de aplicação da recursividade pode ser encontrado nos analisadores
> sintáticos recursivos para linguagens de programação. A grande
> vantagem da recursão está na possibilidade de usar um programa de
> computador finito para definir, analisar ou produzir um estoque
> potencialmente infinito de sentenças, designs ou outros dados.
> <sub>fonte: [wikpedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))</sub>

Aplicando recursividade ao dicionário proposto na pergunta:

```python
def rcontador(v, f=0):
  if len(v) == 0:
    return [] 
  s = v[0]
  return [(f, (f:= f + len(s)) - 1)].extend((rcontador(v[1:-1]),f))

print(rcontador([*dict.values()]))          #[(0, 6), (7, 14), (15, 26)]
```

Answer (score 0):

primeiro vamos percorrer o dicionario com um `for`

```
dict = {'dado1': 'teste01', 'dado2': 'teste002', 'dado3': 'teste0004050'}
tupla = []

for key in dict:
    pass
```

Em seguida vamos adicionar o `len` da `string, somado com o valor anterior

```
dict = {'dado1': 'teste01', 'dado2': 'teste002', 'dado3': 'teste0004050'}
tupla = []
valAnterior = 0

for key in dict:
    tupla.append((valAnterior, valAnterior+len(dict[key])))
    valAnterior += len(dict[key])+1

print(tupla)
```